# Raising ValueError (extra rows) when submitting pipeline.predict into grader

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've been getting a ValueError below when trying to submit my Pipeline into a grader. And I'm not sure where I'm supposed to shave off 12500 rows of data.

```py
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,2].shape[0] == 13892, expected 1544.
```

I've been tasked to build a model that combines the business_features of nursing homes with their cycle 1 survey results, as well as the time between the cycle 1 and cycle 2 survey to predict the cycle 2 total score.

This is my code that I'm using to accomplish the task above.

```py
# Creating a custom transformer to calculate the difference between survey
# 1 & survey 2 times
class TimedeltaTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, t1_col, t2_col):
        self.t1_col = t1_col
        self.t2_col = t2_col

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        self.col_1 = X[self.t1_col].apply(pd.to_datetime)
        self.col_2 = X[self.t2_col].apply(pd.to_datetime)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        difference_list = []
        difference = self.col_1 - self.col_2
        for obj in difference:
            difference_list.append(obj.total_seconds())
        return np.array(difference_list).reshape(-1,1)

# Creating TimedeltaTransformer object
cycle_1_date = 'CYCLE_1_SURVEY_DATE'
cycle_2_date = 'CYCLE_2_SURVEY_DATE'
time_feature = TimedeltaTransformer(cycle_1_date, cycle_2_date)

# Using a custom column selecter transformer to extract cycle_1_features
cycle_1_cols = ['CYCLE_1_DEFS', 'CYCLE_1_NFROMDEFS', 'CYCLE_1_NFROMCOMP',
                'CYCLE_1_DEFS_SCORE', 'CYCLE_1_NUMREVIS',
                'CYCLE_1_REVISIT_SCORE', 'CYCLE_1_TOTAL_SCORE']
cycle_1_features = Pipeline([
    ('cst2', ColumnSelectTransformer(cycle_1_cols)),
    ])

# Creating my survey_model Pipeline object
# Pipeline object is a 2 step process, first a feature union transforming 
# and combining the business features, cycle_1 features as well as time   
# feature; followed by fitting the transformed features into a            
# RandomForestRegressor
survey_model = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('business', business_features),
        ('survey', cycle_1_features),
        ('time', time_feature),
    ])),
    ('forest', RandomForestRegressor()),
])

# Fitting my pipeline produces no error
survey_model.fit(data, cycle_2_score.astype(int))

# Calling the predict function and passing it into the grader raises a ValueError
grader.score.ml__survey_model(survey_model.predict)
```

The fitted pipeline looks like this

```py
Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('features',
                 FeatureUnion(n_jobs=None,
                              transformer_list=[('business',
                                                 FeatureUnion(n_jobs=None,
                                                              transformer_list=[('simple',
                                                                                 Pipeline(memory=None,
                                                                                          steps=[('cst',
                                                                                                  ColumnSelectTransformer(columns=['BEDCERT',
                                                                                                                                   'RESTOT',
                                                                                                                                   'INHOSP',
                                                                                                                                   'CCRC_FACIL',
                                                                                                                                   'SFF',
                                                                                                                                   'CHOW_LAST_12MOS',
                                                                                                                                   'SPRINKLER_STATUS',
                                                                                                                                   'EXP_TOTAL',
                                                                                                                                   'ADJ_TOTAL'])),
                                                                                                 ('imputer',
                                                                                                  SimpleImpute...
                              transformer_weights=None, verbose=False)),
                ('forest',
                 RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=True, criterion='mse',
                                       max_depth=None, max_features='auto',
                                       max_leaf_nodes=None,
                                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
                                       min_impurity_split=None,
                                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                                       n_estimators=10, n_jobs=None,
                                       oob_score=False, random_state=None,
                                       verbose=0, warm_start=False))],
         verbose=False)
```

Some additional context: I'm building this model to have its predict method passed into a custom grader for a project. The grader passes a list of dictionaries to the predict or predict_proba method of my estimator, not a DataFrame. This means that the model must work with both data types. For this reason, I need to provide a custom ColumnSelectTransformer to use instead scikit-learn's own ColumnTransformer.

Below is additional code related to the business features and ColumnSelectTransformer

```py
# Custom transformer to select columns from a dataframe and returns the   
# dataframe as an array
class ColumnSelectTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        return X[self.columns].values

simple_features = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ColumnSelectTransformer(simple_cols)),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
])

owner_onehot = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ColumnSelectTransformer(['OWNERSHIP'])),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('encoder', OneHotEncoder()),
])

cert_onehot = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ColumnSelectTransformer(['CERTIFICATION'])),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('encoder', OneHotEncoder()),
])

categorical_features = FeatureUnion([
    ('owner_onehot', owner_onehot),
    ('cert_onehot', cert_onehot),
])

business_features = FeatureUnion([
    ('simple', simple_features),
    ('categorical', categorical_features)
])
```

Finally, below is the full error raised

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-165-790ca6139493> in <module>()
----> 1 grader.score.ml__survey_model(survey_model.predict)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/static_grader/grader.py in func(*args, **kw)
     92   def __getattr__(self, method):
     93     def func(*args, **kw):
---> 94       return self(method, *args, **kw)
     95     return func
     96 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/static_grader/grader.py in __call__(self, question_name, func)
     88       return
     89     test_cases = json.loads(resp.text)
---> 90     test_cases_grading(question_name, func, test_cases)
     91 
     92   def __getattr__(self, method):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/static_grader/grader.py in test_cases_grading(question_name, func, test_cases)
     40   for test_case in test_cases:
     41     if inspect.isroutine(func):
---> 42       sub_res = func(*test_case['args'], **test_case['kwargs'])
     43     elif not test_case['args'] and not test_case['kwargs']:
     44       sub_res = func

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    114 
    115         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 116         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    117         # update the docstring of the returned function
    118         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    419         Xt = X
    420         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
--> 421             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    422         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    423 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in transform(self, X)
    963             return np.zeros((X.shape[0], 0))
    964         if any(sparse.issparse(f) for f in Xs):
--> 965             Xs = sparse.hstack(Xs).tocsr()
    966         else:
    967             Xs = np.hstack(Xs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    463 
    464     """
--> 465     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    466 
    467 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    584                                                     exp=brow_lengths[i],
    585                                                     got=A.shape[0]))
--> 586                     raise ValueError(msg)
    587 
    588                 if bcol_lengths[j] == 0:

ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,2].shape[0] == 13892, expected 1544.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing my TimeDeltaTransformer helped.

```py
class TimedeltaTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, t1_col, t2_col):
        self.t1_col = t1_col
        self.t2_col = t2_col

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        timedelta_series = (pd.to_datetime(X[self.t1_col]) - pd.to_datetime(X[self.t2_col]))
        array_list = []
        for x in timedelta_series:
            array_list.append(x.total_seconds())
        return np.array(array_list).reshape(-1,1)
```